# Using Retrofit to get data from Autocomplete Google Places API

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I've been reading multiple tutorials (since it's my first time using Retrofit and the Google Places API) and I noticed the pattern of making a POJO class that you create so Retrofit can map the JSON response data to your POJO. Is it possible to create POJOs with only some of the fields, or must I include every single field in a JSON response when creating my POJO? For example, if I have a JSON response structure like this (taken from [Google Places Autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete)):

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "predictions" : [
      {
         "description" : "Paris, France",
         "id" : "691b237b0322f28988f3ce03e321ff72a12167fd",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 5,
               "offset" : 0
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJD7fiBh9u5kcRYJSMaMOCCwQ",
         "reference" : "CjQlAAAA_KB6EEceSTfkteSSF6U0pvumHCoLUboRcDlAH05N1pZJLmOQbYmboEi0SwXBSoI2EhAhj249tFDCVh4R-PXZkPK8GhTBmp_6_lWljaf1joVs1SH2ttB_tw",
         "terms" : [
            {
               "offset" : 0,
               "value" : "Paris"
            },
            {
               "offset" : 7,
               "value" : "France"
            }
         ],
         "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ]
      },
  ...additional results ...
}
```

Obviously I would need a class to hold the values for `status` and `predictions`:

```
public class Result
{
    String status;

    @SerializedName("predictions")
    List<Prediction> predictionList;
}
```

Then for the `Prediction` class, I could have members such as:

```
public class Prediction
{
    String description;
    String id;

    @SerializedName("place_id")
    String placeID;

    String reference;
    List<String> types;
}
```

But would I *need* to include separate objects (ie, create separate classes) for `matched_substrings`, and `terms` even though I plan not to use those values?

A second question I have is how can I only get the JSON response string so I can parse through it myself using Gson. This would help in avoiding having to create a bunch of classes for a large JSON response. I'm just curious in case I ever want to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use the [Places Android API](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/)?

Comment: And this website exists to create Java code from JSON. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: @cricket_007 woah for some reason I did not come across this! I will use this thanks! But still, I would like to know the answer to my questions :] And I knew that website existed but it still creates all those classes for you which was the point of my question.

Comment: I think you would need separate classes, yes. Not sure about including all the attributes

Answer (score 0):

//You can ignoreUnknown keys like this
fun toGooglePredictionsResponse(string: String): GooglePredictionsResponse =
Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true }.decodeFromString(string)

```
//bstrings
@Serializable
data class GooglePredictionsResponse(
    val predictions: List<GooglePrediction>
)

@Serializable
data class StructuredFormating(
    @SerialName("main_text")
    val mainText: String,
    @SerialName("secondary_text")
    val secondaryText: String
)

@Serializable
data class GooglePrediction(
    val place_id: String,
    @SerialName("structured_formatting")
    val structuredFormating: StructuredFormating
)
```